# how to hook $service.id in whmcs (smarty)

Tags: php, smarty, hook, whmcs

I'm trying to add the variable $serviceid onto the clientareahome.tpl in whmcs.

More specifically, I need this link to work on the clientareahome.tpl:

```
<a href="clientarea.php?action=productdetails&amp;id={$serviceid}&amp;dosinglesignon=1">
```

I've gone over the documentation but I'm still confused.

How can I create a hook to call the $serviceid?

Comment: How you read that product/service in the client area home page? is it a loop? add your code please.

Comment: I've managed to figure it out. I'll leave the answer below

Answer (score 0):

With help, we've figured out a solution. I've added this code to the top of the clientareahome.tpl:

```
{php}
$smartyvars = $template->getTemplateVars();  
$userid = $smartyvars['clientsdetails']['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *,tblhosting.id as serviceid FROM tblhosting,tblproducts WHERE userid = $userid AND tblhosting.packageid = tblproducts.id AND tblhosting.domainstatus='Active'"); 
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  
$services = $result["serviceid"];
$template->assign('serviceid', $services);
{/php}
```

For now, it's temporary because in the future, smarty templates may not allow php within the templates. In that case, I would have to make a seperate hook file.